# My date picker is not coming up. want to know What I have missed

Tags: datepicker, nativescript-angular

I am trying to add a datepicker for my mobile app in Native script angular. I used book flight example in Playground as reference. My page is getting blured. My date picker is not coming up.  I am new to native script and java script. I am including my code. Please let me know where I have gone wrong.

I may be missing something.

component.html

```
<GridLayout>
   <ScrollView>
    <GridLayout>
      <StackLayout class="form">

       -------
       ----------

       <TextField hint="Start Date" [(ngModel)]="leaveDetails.startDate" 
         (openSelectDate)="onOpenSelectDate($event)"
         [selectedDate]="selectedDate" 
         [isOnOpenStartDate]="isOnOpenStartDate"
         class="input input-border" (tap)="onOpenSelectDate(true)"> 
      </TextField>



    <TextField hint="End Date" [(ngModel)]="leaveDetails.endDate" 
        class="input input-border" (tap)="onOpenSelectDate(false)"> 
    </TextField> 

    --------
   ---------
 </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>  

<GridLayout row="0" col="0" rowSpan="4" colSpan="2" opacity="0" 
    class="overlay" id="overlayGridLayout"></GridLayout>
<GridLayout row="0" col="0" rowSpan="4" colSpan="2" rows="auto, auto, 
    auto"
    columns="*,*" verticalAlignment="center" visibility="hidden" 
    opacity="0" class="select-date" id="selectDateGridLayout">
    <Label row="0" col="0" colSpan="2" text="Select Date" class="title- 
        select-date"></Label>
    <DatePicker row="1" col="0" colSpan="2" [(ngModel)]="dateSelector"
        (dateChange)="onDateChanged($event)" verticalAlignment="center"> 
    </DatePicker>
    <Button row="2" col="0" text="Cancel" class="btn-next" 
       (tap)="onCloseSelectDate(true)"></Button>
    <Button row="2" col="1" text="OK" class="btn-previous" 
        (tap)="onCloseSelectDate(false)"></Button>
   </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

compoment.ts

```
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { GridLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/grid-layout";
import { Visibility } from "tns-core-modules/ui/enums";


export class CreateleavesComponent {
  leaveDetails : LeaveDetails;
  public selectedDate: Date;
  public isOnOpenStartDate: boolean = false;
  public dateSelector = new Date();
  private _selectDateGridLayout: GridLayout;
  private _overlayGridLayout: GridLayout;


 constructor(private router: Router, private page: Page) {
    this.leaveDetails = new LeaveDetails();
    this.leaveDetails.startDate  = new Date();

    this.leaveDetails.endDate = new Date();
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this._selectDateGridLayout = 
   this.page.getViewById('selectDateGridLayout');
   this._overlayGridLayout = this.page.getViewById('overlayGridLayout');
}



// Select Date
 onOpenSelectDate(event) {
   this.isOnOpenStartDate = event;
   if (this.isOnOpenStartDate) {
       this.dateSelector = this.leaveDetails.startDate || new Date();
   } else {
       this.dateSelector = this.leaveDetails.endDate || new Date();
   }
   this._selectDateGridLayout.visibility = <any>Visibility.visible;
   this._selectDateGridLayout.className = 'select-date';
   this._overlayGridLayout.animate({ opacity: 0.5, duration: 300 });

}

onCloseSelectDate(isCancel: boolean) {
 if (!isCancel) {
    this.selectedDate = this.dateSelector;
    if (this.isOnOpenStartDate) {
        this.leaveDetails.startDate = this.dateSelector;
    } else {
        this.leaveDetails.endDate = this.dateSelector;
    }
}

this._selectDateGridLayout.className = 'select-date';
this._overlayGridLayout.animate({ opacity: 0, duration: 300 })
    .then(() => {
        this._selectDateGridLayout.visibility = <any>Visibility.collapse;
    })
    .catch(() => {
    });
}

onDateChanged(args) {
    let date: Date = args.value;
    this.dateSelector = date;
}


}
```

I tried to get pointers from other question/answers but I am not able to fix my issue.

I expect the date picker to come up when I click on the start date text field.
But the datepicker is not coming up.I have displayed selectDateGridLayout in onOpenSelectDate function and it is getting changed from hidden to visible.

Comment: As you are using Angular I would suggest you to use *ngif instead of accessing them by id in code and toggle visibility .Also your both layout at same position `row="0" col="0" ` , is it intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't imported the Datepicker in your component.  At the top of that component.ts file put:

`import { DatePicker } from "tns-core-modules/ui/date-picker";`